# Let $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ be two measure space. Is $A\times B$ a $\sigma$-Algebra for $X\times Y?$

Tags: measure-theory

I was in measure theory classes, where I was introduced to the concept of sigma algebra, and the following question arose:

Let $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ two measure space. Is the Cartesian product $A\times B$ a $\sigma$-Algebra  for $X\times Y?$

Comment: No.  But sometimes the notation is abused, by writing $A \times B$ for the sigma-algebra generated by the "rectangle" sets $E\times F$ with $E \in A$, $F \in B$.

Comment: I mean... the set of rectangles is not even closed under *finite* union.